# How to check that input string could not be reduced to start symbol in PLY?

Tags: parsing, ply

I'm using PLY to create a parser for a programming language. 
The problem is that the parser returns `None` even if it has not reduced the input string to the starting symbol.

**Short Example to demonstrate the problem**

Starting symbol: program

Input: `{+`

```
def p_program(p):
    'program : LBRACE PLUS RBRACE'
    pass
```

Here, the parser should return some kind of error that EOF was reached and the string could not be reduced. Instead, it just sends `None` to `p_error()`  which is standard for signalling `EOF`.

How do I get to know that the stack could not be reduced and `EOF` was reached?

**Additional details from parser.out**

```
state 1

    (0) S' -> program .



state 2

    (1) program -> LBRACE . PLUS RBRACE

    PLUS            shift and go to state 3


state 3

    (1) program -> LBRACE PLUS . RBRACE

    RBRACE          shift and go to state 4


state 4

    (1) program -> LBRACE PLUS RBRACE .

    $end            reduce using rule 1 (program -> LBRACE PLUS RBRACE .)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `p_error` is called with `None`, then you know that the input could not be reduced to the start symbol because a premature EOF was found.

`p_error` is only called if there is an error; with a correctly written grammar, it will not be called if the parse succeeded by reducing to the start symbol.